# Story ID - Sun ejects a new planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

One of my work mates was talking about this story, any ideas?

"I read a sci fi book once about what happened after the sun ejected a new planet, but I can't remember its name now.

The whole premise of the story was that the solar system, the world and life in general was much less stable than we had been led to believe since the Flood, and that various legends, like "Mars waxing wrath" were holdovers from this. I wish I could remember its name as it was quite good."

### From the co-worker

I'm the co-worker. I read it in a sci-fi paperback over ten years ago, maybe more like fifteen. It was about these people on a space station who were sent to investigate this object the sun had ejected. But while they were investigating the object passed near earth and mars and caused total chaos. All civilization fell apart and most people were killed, and the gravitational forces totally reshaped the surface of the earth and the continents. One theme of the story was this had happened before, recorded in the Indian legends of Vishnu and as a cause of the Great Flood. Earth and Mars passing close together had sucked all the water off mars in a "Jacobs Ladder", a flow visible over the whole earth.

It was quite good. I think it was one of a trilogy.

Comment: Can you ask him if he remembers when he read it and for any other details he might recall? We have a list of details to provide in the `story-identification` tag info.

Comment: I'm the cow-orker. I read it in a sci-fi paperback over ten years ago, maybe more like fiften. It was about these people on a space station who were sent to investigate this object the sun had ejected. But while they were investigating the object passed near earth and mars and caused total chaos. All civilisation fel apart and most people were killed, and the gravitational forces totally reshaped the surface of the earth and the continents. One theme of the story was this had happened before, recorded in the Indian legends of Vishnu and as a cause of the Great Flood. Earth and Mars passing ...

Comment: ... close together had sucked all the water off mars in a "Jacobs Ladder", a flow visible over the whole earth. It was quite good. I think it was one of a trilogy.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I moved your text into the question.

Comment: The description sounds like the plot is based on 'Velikovskyan Catastrophism' ("Worlds in Collision", 1950), which was at it's most controversial in the mid-seventies, with Carl Sagan providing rebuttal.

Comment: @Alastair: Can you check with your co-worker as to whether Vector Gorgoth's answer is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My immediate guess is James Hogan's "[Cradle of Saturn](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/506198.Cradle_of_Saturn)", which has at least one sequel where the protagonists return to Earth after the disaster is over.

> Among the Saturnian moons, farsighted individuals, working without help or permission from any government, have established a colony. They call themselves the Kronians, after the Greek name for Saturn. Operating without the hidebound restrictions of bureaucratic Earth, the colony is a magnet, attracting the best and brightest of the home world, and has been making important new discoveries. But one of their claims -- that they have found proof that the Solar System has undergone repeated cataclysms, and as recently as a few thousand years ago -- flies in the face of the reigning dogma, and is under attack by the scientific establishment.
>
> **Then the planet Jupiter emits a white-hot protoplanet as large as the Earth, which is hurtling sunwards like a gigantic comet that will obliterate civilization....**